# Use SQL Server to get all the data from XML nodes named the same

Tags: sql-server, xml, nodes

I have an XML file where the nodes that I need the data from are all named the same.  I understand how to access the first (or second record) so the following query only gives me the second author (the `<a1>` tag).  How do I get all the authors as a single column ?

```
      DECLARE @MyXML XML
      SET @MyXML = '<refworks>
            <reference>
               <rt>Journal Article</rt> 
               <sr>Print(0)</sr> 
               <id>869</id> 
               <a1>Aabye,Martine G.</a1> 
               <a1>Hermansen,Thomas Stig</a1> 
               <a1>Ruhwald,Morten</a1> 
               <a1>PrayGod,George</a1> 
               <a1>Faurholt-Jepsen,Daniel</a1> 
               <a1>Jeremiah,Kidola</a1> 
               <a1>Faurholt-Jepsen,Maria</a1> 
               <a1>Range,Nyagosya</a1> 
           </reference>
         </refworks>'

      SELECT 
          author.value('(a1)[2]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS 'Author'
      FROM @MyXML.nodes('/refworks/reference') AS ref(author)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this :-

```
  SELECT 
      author.value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS 'Author'
  FROM @MyXML.nodes('//refworks/reference/child::node()') AS ref(author)
  where  author.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(100)') ='a1'
```

child::node() represents an axis specifier which is `child` and `::` is the axis separator.

For understanding child axis which is used to drill down in the node can be found in this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms345122%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) document.

or [manipulating xml data in sql server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/manipulating-xml-data-in-sql-server/)

Updated :-

A much simplier way You were on the right track .Specify the child node in the from clause for filtering the data

```
 SELECT 
      author.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS 'Author'
  FROM @MyXML.nodes('/refworks/reference/a1') AS ref(author)
```

Comment: Awesome - many thanks.  Can you point me some link that explains what it is doing ?

Comment: Let me know if you still have doubts after going thru the docs

Comment: @praveen can you please take a look at my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27638108/how-to-get-specific-result-from-a-search-in-a-sql-column-populated-with-xml