# Updating existing temp table with id created during set based insert

Tags: sql-server, xml, output

I have extracted some `XML` into a temporary table as follows:

```
declare @INT_ParticipantID INT = 1
declare @XML_Results XML = '
<roots>
  <root>
    <ID />
    <ResultDateTime>2016-08-16T13:58:21.484Z</ResultDateTime>
    <Test>
      <ID>5</ID>
      <ParticipantID>0</ParticipantID>
      <Instrument />
      <ControlSet />
      <Assay />
      <CreationDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</CreationDate>
      <StartDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</StartDate>
      <EndDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</EndDate>
      <Closed>false</Closed>
      <SlideGenNumber>0</SlideGenNumber>
    </Test>
    <EnteredByInitials />
    <ControlSetLots />
    <LotResult1 />
    <LotResult2 />
    <LotResult3 />
    <LotResults>
      <ID>13</ID>
      <LotNumber />
      <LotName />
      <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</ExpiryDate>
      <Result>
        <ID />
        <Count>1</Count>
        <Mean>2</Mean>
        <SD>3</SD>
      </Result>
      <ParticipantID>0</ParticipantID>
      <ApprovalStatus>false</ApprovalStatus>
      <LotAnalytes />
      <LotInstruments />
      <TestDetails />
    </LotResults>
    <LotResults>
      <ID>14</ID>
      <LotNumber />
      <LotName />
      <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</ExpiryDate>
      <Result>
        <ID />
        <Count>4</Count>
        <Mean>5</Mean>
        <SD>6</SD>
      </Result>
      <ParticipantID>0</ParticipantID>
      <ApprovalStatus>false</ApprovalStatus>
      <LotAnalytes />
      <LotInstruments />
      <TestDetails />
    </LotResults>
    <LotResults>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <LotNumber />
      <LotName />
      <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</ExpiryDate>
      <Result>
        <ID />
        <Count>1</Count>
        <Mean>0</Mean>
        <SD>0</SD>
      </Result>
      <ParticipantID>0</ParticipantID>
      <ApprovalStatus>false</ApprovalStatus>
      <LotAnalytes />
      <LotInstruments />
      <TestDetails />
    </LotResults>
    <StandardComment>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <EnteredBy />
      <Description />
    </StandardComment>
    <ReviewComment>
      <ID />
      <EnteredBy />
      <Description />
    </ReviewComment>
  </root>
</roots>
'

  SELECT r.value('ID[1]','int') AS Transaction_ID
        ,r.value('ResultDateTime[1]', 'datetime') AS Transaction_DateTime
        ,r.value('(Test/ID)[1]', 'int') AS QCTest_ID
        ,lr.value('ID[1]','int') AS Lot_ID
        ,lr.value('(Result/Count)[1]','int') AS Result_Count
        ,lr.value('(Result/Mean)[1]','decimal(18, 8)') AS Result_Mean
        ,lr.value('(Result/SD)[1]','decimal(18, 8)') AS Result_SD
        ,r.value('(StandardComment/ID)[1]','int') AS StandardComment_ID 
        ,r.value('(ReviewComment/ID)[1]','int') AS ReviewComment_ID 
    INTO #tempRawXML
    FROM @XML_Results.nodes('/roots/root') AS A(r)
   CROSS 
   APPLY r.nodes('LotResults') AS B(lr)
```

This brings me back the result set below:

[image: Result set returned when extracting XML]

I need to insert the results extracted into two tables - one is a mapping table and the other is determined by the `Lot_ID` field sent through the `XML`.

What I need to achieve is an `INSERT` into the mapping table, then extract the newly generated primary key field (which is an `IDENTITY`) and `INSERT` it into the relevant table(s) along with the remaining result data.

The most efficient way I can think to do this would be to `UPDATE` the existing `Transaction_ID` column in the `#tempRawXML` table with the `OUTPUT` of the first `INSERT` operation. Is there a way I can achieve this? So far I have the following - which creates a new row in the `#tempRawXML` table with the relevant `Transaction_ID`:

```
INSERT 
     INTO dbo.Result_Transaction_Mapping
        (
            fk_participant_id,
            fk_test_id,
            result_date_time,
            fk_comment_id,
            fk_review_comment_id
        )
   OUTPUT INSERTED.pk_id 
     INTO #tempRawXML(Transaction_ID)
   SELECT @INT_ParticipantID,
          QCTest_ID,
          Transaction_DateTime,
          StandardComment_ID,
          ReviewComment_ID
     FROM #tempRawXML
```

[image: How the temp table looks following the insert]

Is there a way I can modify the above so that instead of inserting new rows containing only the generated `Transaction_ID`, it updates the existing row in `#tempRawXML`?

Comment: Insert the output into a fresh temporary table. You will need a unique identifier in your output to match the rows from #tempRawXML, then you can update them easily.

Comment: @Pawel thanks for the suggestion. I am hoping to find a solution more suited to my original question (if there is a way to `UPDATE` the original temp table).  If this does not work out then I will look into your proposed solution.

Comment: For a generic solution some missing information: Why are there empty `ID` elements? Is this a heavily used *multi-user-database* (might there be concurring inserts which influence your newly created IDs)? There is `LotResult1,2,3` and `LotResults` with one `ID` and one `Result` but no nesting level for this data in `LotResults`. Might the be more than one? Is this 1:n?. Are the IDs in `LotResults` the *real* IDs you want to use in your tables?

Comment: @Shnugo thanks for getting back. _Why are there empty `ID` elements?_ All fields visible in the XML file are part of a C# object. Therefore certain aspects of this object will only be populated in certain scenarios i.e. when reading/updating `results` from/to the database. _multi-user-database_ Yes it is. _`LotResult1,2,3`/`LotResults`_ Please ignore `LotResult1,2,3` fields - they were used in testing. All results will be exposed through the `LotResults` field. _Are the IDs in `LotResults` the real IDs?_ No these are the `LotIDs` used to determine which table to save the result details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for a way to `UPDATE` the original `tempRawXML` table - to no avail - I have a solution for the initial problem using a combination of:

XML used:

```
declare @XML_Results XML = '
<roots>
  <root>
    <ID>-2</ID>
    <ResultDateTime>2016-08-24T10:44:22.829Z</ResultDateTime>
    <Test>
      <ID>5</ID>
      <ParticipantID>0</ParticipantID>
      <Instrument />
      <ControlSet />
      <Assay />
      <CreationDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</CreationDate>
      <StartDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</StartDate>
      <EndDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</EndDate>
      <Closed>false</Closed>
      <SlideGenNumber>0</SlideGenNumber>
    </Test>
    <EnteredByInitials />
    <ControlSetLots />        
    <LotResults>
      <ID>13</ID>
      <LotNumber />
      <LotName />
      <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</ExpiryDate>
      <Result>
        <ID />
        <Count>5</Count>
        <Mean>6</Mean>
        <SD>7</SD>
      </Result>
      <ParticipantID>0</ParticipantID>
      <ApprovalStatus>false</ApprovalStatus>
      <LotAnalytes />
      <LotInstruments />
      <TestDetails />
    </LotResults>
    <LotResults>
      <ID>14</ID>
      <LotNumber />
      <LotName />
      <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</ExpiryDate>
      <Result>
        <ID />
        <Count>1</Count>
        <Mean>0</Mean>
        <SD>0</SD>
      </Result>
      <ParticipantID>0</ParticipantID>
      <ApprovalStatus>false</ApprovalStatus>
      <LotAnalytes />
      <LotInstruments />
      <TestDetails />
    </LotResults>
    <LotResults>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <LotNumber />
      <LotName />
      <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</ExpiryDate>
      <Result>
        <ID />
        <Count>1</Count>
        <Mean>0</Mean>
        <SD>0</SD>
      </Result>
      <ParticipantID>0</ParticipantID>
      <ApprovalStatus>false</ApprovalStatus>
      <LotAnalytes />
      <LotInstruments />
      <TestDetails />
    </LotResults>
    <StandardComment>
      <ID />
      <EnteredBy />
      <Description />
    </StandardComment>
    <ReviewComment>
      <ID />
      <EnteredBy />
      <Description />
    </ReviewComment>
  </root>
  <root>
    <ID>-1</ID>
    <ResultDateTime>2016-08-24T10:44:22.829Z</ResultDateTime>
    <Test>
      <ID>5</ID>
      <ParticipantID>0</ParticipantID>
      <Instrument />
      <ControlSet />
      <Assay />
      <CreationDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</CreationDate>
      <StartDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</StartDate>
      <EndDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</EndDate>
      <Closed>false</Closed>
      <SlideGenNumber>0</SlideGenNumber>
    </Test>
    <EnteredByInitials />
    <ControlSetLots />        
    <LotResults>
      <ID>13</ID>
      <LotNumber />
      <LotName />
      <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</ExpiryDate>
      <Result>
        <ID />
        <Count>1</Count>
        <Mean>0</Mean>
        <SD>0</SD>
      </Result>
      <ParticipantID>0</ParticipantID>
      <ApprovalStatus>false</ApprovalStatus>
      <LotAnalytes />
      <LotInstruments />
      <TestDetails />
    </LotResults>
    <LotResults>
      <ID>14</ID>
      <LotNumber />
      <LotName />
      <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</ExpiryDate>
      <Result>
        <ID />
        <Count>1</Count>
        <Mean>2</Mean>
        <SD>3</SD>
      </Result>
      <ParticipantID>0</ParticipantID>
      <ApprovalStatus>false</ApprovalStatus>
      <LotAnalytes />
      <LotInstruments />
      <TestDetails />
    </LotResults>
    <LotResults>
      <ID>0</ID>
      <LotNumber />
      <LotName />
      <ExpiryDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</ExpiryDate>
      <Result>
        <ID />
        <Count>1</Count>
        <Mean>0</Mean>
        <SD>0</SD>
      </Result>
      <ParticipantID>0</ParticipantID>
      <ApprovalStatus>false</ApprovalStatus>
      <LotAnalytes />
      <LotInstruments />
      <TestDetails />
    </LotResults>
    <StandardComment>
      <ID />
      <EnteredBy />
      <Description />
    </StandardComment>
    <ReviewComment>
      <ID />
      <EnteredBy />
      <Description />
    </ReviewComment>
  </root>
</roots>
'
```

1) An additional temporary table for 'mapping' UI to `IDENTITY` generated IDs (thanks to @Pawel for the suggestion to get me on the right track). 
NOTE: I am sending an incremental negative value from the UI for the `Old_ID` field to ensure that these values can never match up with an existing `IDENTITY`.

```
  -- Hold mappings between old and processed IDs
  -- Used when inserting into relevant lot tables following initial top level transaction insert
  CREATE 
   TABLE #Processed_Transactions 
       (
        Old_ID INT, -- ID supplied by UI (using a negative number to ensure no conflict with IDs from Result_Transaction_Mapping table)
        ProcessedTransaction_ID INT -- ID generated during initial insert into Result_Transaction_Mapping table
       )
```

2) `MERGE` combined with `OUTPUT` to insert the initial transaction into the and track the `Old_ID` / `ProcessedTransaction_ID` fields in the mapping temporary table.
A 1=0 scenario is raised at this point to ensure the `INSERT` is always triggered. This seems a little iffy but seems to be widely used.

[Example from another question using `MERGE` instead of `INSERT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10950418/6224482)

```
   -- Function to insert the top level Result Transaction
   -- Required to populate OUTPUT variable in Processed_Transactions temporary table
   MERGE dbo.Result_Transaction_Mapping AS RTM 
   USING 
       (
          -- Extracts distinct UI assigned IDs and column information
          SELECT DISTINCT Assigned_ID, 
                 MAX(Transaction_DateTime) AS Transaction_DateTime, 
                 MAX(QCTest_ID) as QCTest_ID, 
                 MAX(StandardComment_ID) AS StandardComment_ID, 
                 MAX(ReviewComment_ID) AS ReviewComment_ID, 
                 MAX(Result_Count) AS Result_Count, 
                 MAX(Result_Mean) AS Result_Mean, 
                 MAX(Result_SD) AS Result_SD 
            FROM #tempRawXML 
           GROUP 
              BY Assigned_ID
      ) AS TR
     -- Create 1 = 0 scenario to ensure the IDs never match up to what currently exists in the Result_Transaction_Mapping table
     ON TR.Assigned_ID = RTM.pk_id
   WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    -- Ensure at least one of the transaction result columns contain a value
    -- This will also be verified on the UI
    AND TR.Result_Count > 0
    AND TR.Result_Mean > 0.0
    AND TR.Result_SD > 0.0
   THEN
 INSERT 
      (
        fk_participant_id, 
        fk_test_id, 
        result_date_time, 
        fk_comment_id, 
        fk_review_comment_id
      )
 VALUES 
      (
        @INT_ParticipantID, 
        TR.QCTest_ID, 
        TR.Transaction_DateTime, 
        TR.StandardComment_ID, 
        TR.ReviewComment_ID
      )   
 -- Following insert of a result, populate the INSERTED primary key field into the mappings table
 OUTPUT TR.Assigned_ID, 
        INSERTED.pk_id
   INTO #Processed_Transactions 
      (
        Old_ID, 
        ProcessedTransaction_ID
      );
```

Following this, I now have a combination of datasets which can be used to insert into the relevant `Lot` tables.

**`#tempRawXML` table**

[image: Temp Raw XML table]

**`ID mappings` with UI negative mappings and `IDENTITY` IDs generated by the table**

[image: ID Mappings table]

Which leads me to another predicament - the use of `CURSORS` and thus venturing back into the *"dark acres of procedural approaches"* (strongly advised against by @Shnugo [in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38761113/6224482) who I would imagine is 'curs'ing my name right about now.

Following a successful top-level result transaction `INSERT` and using the raw XML and the generated IDs above, I need to insert the remainder of the 'result specific' information to their own respective tables, the names of which have yet to be determined based on the result `LotID`. I have therefore setup the following combination of procedural, set based, dynamic SQL (if there is such a thing) to accomplish this:

```
 -- recursively access each associated Lot table based on associated Lot ID's
 DECLARE @LotNumber NVARCHAR(20), @LotID INT 
 -- Querystring to hold all set update calls
 DECLARE @ResultQueryString NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
 DECLARE Lot_Cursor
  CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
     FOR
      -- Select the lot numbers based on the available IDs
      SELECT 
    DISTINCT L.pk_id AS LotID,
             L.number AS LotNumber
        FROM dbo.Lot L
        LEFT
        JOIN #tempRawXML TR 
          ON TR.Lot_ID = L.pk_id
       WHERE L.pk_id IN (TR.Lot_ID)

        OPEN Lot_Cursor

       FETCH 
        NEXT 
        FROM Lot_Cursor
        INTO @LotID, @LotNumber

       WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
       BEGIN
         SET @ResultQueryString +=
           N'  MERGE dbo.[' + @LotNumber + '] AS L
               USING 
                    (
                        SELECT PT.ProcessedTransaction_ID,
                               TR.Result_ID,
                               TR.Result_Count, 
                               TR.Result_Mean, 
                               TR.Result_SD 
                          FROM #tempRawXML TR
                          JOIN #Processed_Transactions PT
                            ON PT.Old_ID = TR.Assigned_ID
                         WHERE TR.Lot_ID = '+ CAST(@LotID AS NVARCHAR(20)) +'
                    ) R
                 ON R.Result_ID = L.pk_id   
               WHEN NOT MATCHED     
                AND R.Result_Count > 0
                AND R.Result_Mean > 0.0
                AND R.Result_SD > 0.0       
               THEN
             INSERT
                  (
                     fk_result_transaction_mapping_id,
                     count,
                     mean,
                     standard_deviation,
                     result_status              
                  )
             VALUES
                  (
                     R.ProcessedTransaction_ID,
                     R.Result_Count,
                     R.Result_Mean,
                     R.Result_SD,
                     1
                  ); '            

       FETCH
        NEXT
        FROM Lot_Cursor
        INTO @LotID, @LotNumber

         END
       CLOSE Lot_Cursor
  DEALLOCATE Lot_Cursor        

        -- @Processed_Transactions temp table variable must be declared when executing dynamic sql
        --EXEC sp_executesql @ResultQueryString, N'@Processed_Transactions MyTable READONLY', @Processed_Transactions=@Processed_Transactions
        EXEC (@ResultQueryString)
```

My follow-up question here - is this an acceptable use of `CURSORS` (bearing in mind that there can only be a maximum of 6 iterations)? Additionally, is there a way I can avoid the use of `CURSOR`s in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Your question and your answer is quite a lot to read...

I want to offer you a very reduced [MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to boild down your needs to the actual problem - as far as I understand it...

The following solution has one tiny need: The table with the `IDENTITY` ID must have a column for temporary storage of an external ID. If this is possible, you could use this much simpler approach:

```
--This table must have a column for temporary storage of the external ID
DECLARE @TableWithExistingData TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeData VARCHAR(100),ExternalID INT);
INSERT INTO @TableWithExistingData(SomeData) VALUES
('Data for ID=1'),('Data for ID=2');

--This is the existing data
SELECT * FROM @TableWithExistingData

--This is the derived table from your XML. 
--You can use ROW_NUMBER() to create a running number on the fly.
--Use this as the rows temporary ID
--These new rows should be inserted in the table with existing data
--DataForOtherTable should be inserted in another table but with the newly created ID as FK
DECLARE @NewRows TABLE(ID INT,SomeNewData VARCHAR(100),DataForOtherTable VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @NewRows(ID,SomeNewData,DataForOtherTable) VALUES
(1,'New value 1','More data 1'),(2,'New value 2','More data 2');

--This table will hold the newly created ID and the external ID
DECLARE @Mapping TABLE(nwID INT,extID INT);

--OUTPUT is great but can only return columns of the target table, 
--hence the need to have the external ID within your table
INSERT INTO @TableWithExistingData(SomeData,ExternalID)
OUTPUT inserted.ID,inserted.ExternalID INTO @Mapping
SELECT nr.SomeNewData,nr.ID 
FROM @NewRows AS nr;

--This is your other existing table, where you want to store values with the new ID as FK
DECLARE @SideTable TABLE(NewlyCreatedID INT,AndMoreDataForOtherTable VARCHAR(100));

--use the mapping table to get the ID into the table
INSERT INTO @SideTable
SELECT nwID,nr.DataForOtherTable 
FROM @Mapping AS m
INNER JOIN @NewRows AS nr ON m.extID=nr.ID

--And this is the result in all tables
SELECT * FROM @NewRows
SELECT * FROM @TableWithExistingData
SELECT * FROM @SideTable;
```

One point to consider: If you use `ROW_NUMBER` and there is the same process happening in the same seconds, you might mix your external ID with the other process... You could use GUIDs or concatenate the `ROW_NUMBER` with a unique sessionID or whatever you can use there...